# Is there a way to access hardware directly in Python?

Tags: python, hardware, graphics

I want to learn about graphical libraries by myself and toy with them a bit. I built a small program that defines lines and shapes as lists of pixels, but I cannot find a way to access the screen directly so that I can display the points on the screen without any intermediate.

What I mean is that I do not want to use any prebuilt graphical library such as gnome, cocoa, etc. I usually use Python to code and my program uses Python, but I can also code and integrate C modules with it.

I am aware that accessing the screen hardware directly takes away the multiplatform side of Python, but I disregard it for the sake of learning. So: is there any way to access the hardware directly in Python, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Nobody, not even state-of-the-art video games (most of the time, anyway) does things that low-level. That's driver work. For virtually all applications, it's entirely impractical: Insanly complicated, hard to impossible to port across sufficently different hardware, and prone to breaking whenever the hardware vendor improves something (e.g. extends the pipeline), and that's just off the top of my head. There's nothing to be learnt from that, unless you want to write drivers. We have DirectX, OpenGL, etc. for a reason. And you can access those (or at least OpenGL) just fine from Python.

Comment: @delnan Yeah but op doesn't really have to justify why he wants to learn, if the question is valid. What if he wants to write drivers? `Insanly complicated, hard to impossible to port across sufficently different hardware, and prone to breaking whenever the hardware vendor improves something` How does all this relate to turning a pixel on and off? That's the question, everything else are your widely speculative opinions. Getting to show just a pixel    is a fantastic learning experience.

Comment: You may be right. But my impression is that OP is under a wrong impression of what constitutes low-level graphic programming.

Comment: @delnan Well, let him learn the hard way :)

Comment: Switching pixels on and off is basically what I want to do. I know that doing something at such a low level is impractical for anything that can actually be used, but before I begin to use  higher level APIs, I want to understand how the underlying software works, or at least have an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a great self-learning path and I would add my two-cents worth and suggest you consider looking at the **GObject**, **Cairo** and **Pygame** modules some time.

The Python **GObject** module may be at a higher level than your current interest, but it enables pixel level drawing with **Cairo** (see the [home page](http://cairographics.org/)) as well as providing a general base for portable GUI apps using Python

**Pygame** also has pixel level methods as well as access methods to the graphics drivers (at the higher level) - here is a quick [code example](http://rene.f0o.com/mywiki/LectureThree)

Answer (score 7):

No, Python isn't the best choice for this type of raw hardware access to the video card.  I would recommend writing C in DOS.  Well, actually, I don't recommend it.  It's a horrible thing to do.  But, it's how I learned to do it, and it's probably about as friendly as you are going to get for accessing hardware directly without any intermediate.

I say DOS rather than Linux or NT because neither of those will give you direct access to the video hardware without writing a driver.  That means having to learn the whole driver API, and you need to invoke a lot of "magic," that won't be very obvious because writing a video driver in Windows NT is fairly complicated.

I say C rather than Python because it gives you real pointers, and the ability to do stupid things with them.  Under DOS, you can write to arbitrary physical memory addresses in C, which seems to be what you want.  Trying to get Python working at all under an OS terrible enough to allow you direct hardware access would be a frustration in itself, even if you only wanted to do simple stuff that Python is good at.

And, as others have said, don't expect to use anything that you learn with this project in the real world.  It may be interesting, but if you tried to write a real application in this way, you'd promptly be shot by whoever would have to maintain your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather an old thread now, but I stumbled upon it while musing the same question.

I used to program in assembly language. In my day, drawing on screen was simply(?) a matter of poking a value into a memory location. The value turned a pixel on or off and defined its colour.

The term 'poke' comes from Basic by the way, not assembler. In assembler, you had to write a value into a data register then tell the processor where to put the data using another command and specifying an address register, usually in hexadecimal form! And each different processor had its own assembly language. But hec was the code fast!

As hardware progressed, I found that graphics hardware programming became more and more complex. There's much more to it than now simply defining a pixel. The graphics subsystem has its own processor -- or processors -- and it's that that you've got to learn to talk to. The processor doesn't just plonk stuff in memory locations. (I believe that what used to be the fastest supercomputer in the world for a while ran on graphics chips!) 'Plonk' is not a Basic command by the way.

Sorry; I digress. In answer to the original poster's query, I believe that the goal of understanding the graphics-drawing process could have been best achieved by experimenting with a Raspberry Pi. It's Python compatible and hence perfect for the job. Its hardware is well documented and it's cheap and easy to use.

Hope this helps someone, Cheers, M